# Apache log4j asynchronous Loggers for Low-Latency Logging

Tags: asynchronous, logging, log4j

If application server crashes and huge log is pending to be persisted into the log file, how log4j Asynchronous Logger handle to avoid missing any log? Or is there any mechanism to retrieve the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In graceful shutdown no log is lost, whereas, in crash or killing process, may lose the log and I could not find any approach to return the lost logs.